# fuzzy matching address data

Tags: python, postgresql

I have the task of matching two lists of names and addresses - represented in two database tables in PostgreSQL.

Address data can be strings like *Otto-Johannsen-Straße  7* or even *Otto-Johannsen-Str. 7 Wohnung oben* which have to match to *Otto-Johannsen-Str. 7*. Names can look be things like *Antje's Hus* which should match with some probability to *Antje* or *Haus am Meer* should match to *Hotel Haus am Meer*.

So it is about fuzzy matching - but soundex() and even levenshtein() won't help too much, because it's part's of strings hat have to be taken into account. With levenshtein() for instance the best match for *Abendsonne* was "Undine" - but the better match for my data would have been *Hotel Abendsonne".

I envision to have some probability measure with matches - so my result should be a list of matches with probabilities ideally.

How should I approach this problem - which matching algorithms should I use?
And is this a task I would directly do in PostgreSQL - of is it maybe a better approach to use Python?

Comment: This seems to rely heavily on domain specific knowledge.  It might be best addressed to geographers, or Germans, or German-speaking geographers.

Answer (score 3):

In my hands, the two examples you show are tied.  Unless the `*` is part of the string and not a typo.

```
select levenshtein('Abendsonne','Hotel Abendsonne'), levenshtein('Abendsonne','Undine');
 levenshtein | levenshtein
-------------+-------------
           6 |           6
```

However, the similarity method from pg_trgm gives results much more like what you probably want:

```
select similarity('Abendsonne','Undine'), similarity('Abendsonne','Hotel Abendsonne');
 similarity | similarity
------------+------------
 0.05882353 | 0.64705884
```

And unlike Levenshtein, can support indexes for fast look-up.

The main problem with the first way being that Levenshtein is very sensitive to the strings being unequal lengths, while pg_trgm is somewhat less sensitive to that.

The postgis extension contains some code for standardizing addresses, although I don't have much experience with using it, or any at all at using it in other languages.  It is probably worth a look.

Another approach would be to strip out noise words, like 'Straße' and 'Hotel', from both sides before doing the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a geocoder, you can translate each full-text addresses/name to a coordinate pair (or a set of N most likely coordinate pairs) and do your matching based on that. Internally, geocoders do exactly what you're trying to do - understand all variations of how the same location can be addressed.

The [TIGER geocoder](https://postgis.net/docs/Extras.html#Tiger_Geocoder) included in PostGIS is US-specific, so it needs some tinkering to get it to work elsewhere. OpenStreetMap offers [Nominatim](https://nominatim.org/) you can self-host. There's also an entire market of paid APIs: [GCloud](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/overview), [AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/location/latest/developerguide/search-place-index-geocoding.html), [Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/how-to-search-for-address#request-latitude-and-longitude-for-an-address-geocoding) all have one but there are also entire [marketplaces](https://rapidapi.com/search/geocoding) of smaller vendors which you can usually try out to some extent with a free tier.

If you decide to build your own, you can benchmark it against those. If you come out on top, consider [contributing](https://github.com/osm-search/Nominatim) to the open ones.